# Stop printing repeated arithmetic expressions

Tags: c

I wrote this program in C to find all sums of three numbers that equal number n:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int n;
  printf("n:");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int a,b,c;
  a=0;
  while(a<n)
  {
    a++;
    b = 0;
    while (b < n)
    {
      b++;
      c = 1;
      while (c < n)
      {
         if(a + b + c == n){
            printf("%d + %d + %d = %d\n", a , b ,c ,n);
            c++;
         }
         if (a + b + c != n){
            c++;
         }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

What do I do to stop it from printing repeated arithmetic expressions, like 1 + 1 + 3 and 3 + 1 + 1, for example.

Comment: Instead of `while` like this, consider using `for`.

Comment: So you want to ignore order? How about enforcing a ≤ b ≤ c by starting *b* at *a* and *c* at *b*? (Also, think about how many different values of *c* work for a given *a*, *b*, and *n*.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something similar to what Ry-♦ suggested in the comments to your question. 
Here is what it would look like in your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int n;
  printf("n:");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int a,b,c;
  a=0;
  while(a<n)
  {
    a++;
    b = a; /* start b at a to prevent duplicate sequences */
    while (b < n)
    {
      b++;
      c = b; /* start c at b to prevent duplicate sequences */
      while (c < n)
      {
         if(a + b + c == n){
            printf("%d + %d + %d = %d\n", a , b ,c ,n);
            c++;
         }
         if (a + b + c != n){
            c++;
         }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also in the comments of your question is a suggestion to use for loops. This would make your code a lot more compact and easier to read:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int n;
  printf("n:");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int a,b,c;
  for(a=0;a<n;a++)
    for(b=a;b<n;b++)
      for(c=b;c<n;c++)
         if(a + b + c == n)
            printf("%d + %d + %d = %d\n", a , b ,c ,n);
}
```